# Wireless disconnects after a few minutes on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, wireless, connection

I've posted [here](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/8559521/) the content of `my wireless-info-txt`.

Wifi is working fine on Windows OS. Well, after a ten minutes approx. the connection drops and I have to disable and enable Wifi again to have connection.

Comment: It seems that connection drops when there is no traffic for a while...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After trying hundred suggestions I saw in forums, as disabling N-mode, without success. Finally, I discovered it seems to be problem of my router. I had set channel 6 on the router. Since I set router channel to auto, problem fixed.